# Unable to decode input data

Tags: ether, etherscan

I am trying to decode input data from a transaction but am not receiving expected results from various decoding methods. Based on my troubleshooting I suspect there is something regarding the ABI input I am providing when decoding my input data for the transactions. The ABI contents I am using were received from Etherscan for the Aave collector contract which is below.

```
[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"admin","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"implementation","type":"address"}],"name":"Upgraded","type":"event"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"inputs":[],"name":"admin","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"implementation","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_logic","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"initialize","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newImplementation","type":"address"}],"name":"upgradeTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newImplementation","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"upgradeToAndCall","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]
```

When I run the following I do not receive my expected output.

```
    const InputDataDecoder = require('ethereum-input-data-decoder');
    const abi = require('../data/abi.json');
    const decoder = new InputDataDecoder(abi);

    const data = '0xa415bcad000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb4800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005d21dba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006576f802d9b685896e1b710cccae9af8f3ce368f';

    const result = decoder.decodeData(data);
```

Instead I receive a null response for the method

```
{
  method: null,
  types: [ 'address' ],
  inputs: [ '0x00000000000000000000000000000005d21Dba00' ],
  names: [ 'admin' ]
}
```

On Etherscan I expect the following result when decoding the input data for this transaction: 0xffc11133bd95549b6682a8c6f3bfe9b8a0518af894824bf82db6c0c4939a31f2
[image]

I've also tried using ConsenSys/abi-decoder but am receiving an undefined output.

```
const abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder'); 
const abi = require('../data/abi.json');

abiDecoder.addABI(abi);
const testData = "0xa415bcad000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb4800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005d21dba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006576f802d9b685896e1b710cccae9af8f3ce368f";
const decodedData = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(testData);

I am unable to determine why the decoding will not function as expected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That abi you shared doesn't have the `borrow(address,uint256,uint256,uint16,address)` definition and inputs. Maybe that's why the `abi-decoder` is not able to recognize and is not able to decode it.

The first 4 bytes of the `keccak-256` hash of the `borrow(address,uint256,uint256,uint16,address)` function is: `0xa415bcad`. When the `abi-decoder` tries to match the first 4 bytes of the data, `0xa415bcad`, to a function of the provided abi, it doesn't find it, so it doesn't know how to decode it.

I suggest you update that abi to include the `borrow(address,uint256,uint256,uint16,address)` function definition.

If you can't, and you know the types of inputs, then you can manually remove the function selector and decode de data with something like `web3` like this:

```js
const removeFunctionSelector = (data) => {
  // Removes the function signature from the data (the first 10 characters)
  // It assumes that the `data` always has the `0x` prefix. It adds it again after removing the function signature.
  return `0x${data.substring(10)}`;
};

const data =
  "0xa415bcad000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb4800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005d21dba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006576f802d9b685896e1b710cccae9af8f3ce368f";

const decoded = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(
  // Decoding event data. Exclude the `indexed` parameters.
  ["address", "uint256", "uint256", "uint16", "address"],
  removeFunctionSelector(data)
);

console.log("decoded: ", decoded);
```

That printed for me:

```
decoded:  Result {
  '0': '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
  '1': '25000000000',
  '2': '2',
  '3': '0',
  '4': '0x6576F802D9b685896e1b710CccAE9af8F3cE368F',
  __length__: 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there any reason the ABI on etherscan would not include certain functions?